# Getting "No parameterless constructor found" with protobuf-net in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm trying to deserialize an object that is a collection. The class contained in the collection is an inherited class from a base class.

```
Public MustInherit Class EntityBase
    Protected Sub New()
        Initialize()
    End Sub
End Class

Partial Public Class [BarEntity]
    Inherits EntityBase
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In this case the collection contains the BarEntity class. However at the time that I'm calling the deserializer in protobuf-net like this

```
Dim byteafter() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(CType(oWSResult.Obj, String))
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(byteafter)
myList = Serializer.Deserialize(Of BarEntityCollection)(ms)
```

is throwing this **No parameterless constructor found for EntityBase**

This code is being executed in a Compact Framework 3.5 app.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well that looks odd - can you tell me what version number of protobuf-net you are using? Thanks. I won't be able to logo at it "right now" - but will look this weekend if you can confirm the version number,

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the quick answer. It is the r622.

Comment: Still no way around this :(

Comment: my apologies, but I am at a conference and my travel laptop lacks the CF tooling. My work desktop has a range of VMs for various platforms.